# How to delete from database where multiple conditions are met?

Tags: database, prisma

I'm trying to delete a row in my database using Prisma, where I want to delete it only if two conditions are met, `slug` and `userId`.

This is what I have tried to do:

```js
const deleteComment = await prisma.favorites.delete({
      where: {
        slug: slug,
        userId: userId,
      },
    });
```

This is my model in schema.prisma:

```js
model Favorites {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  slug        String  @db.VarChar(128)
  contentType String? @db.VarChar(128)
  userId      String
  user        User?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}
```

If I remove the `userId: userId,` it deletes all rows containing the same slug, which is not ideal if multiple users have added the same slug.

How can I delete a row when both conditions are met?

Comment: After removing `userId: userId`, which rows do you expect to be deleted?

Comment: @some-user It was just to inform you that I can delete it from the database, but I only want the row to get deleted if it can find the same userId and the slug I pass along.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't specify attributes sufficiently to identify a unique row (guaranteed by the schema), you should use `deleteMany` instead of `delete`.

```js
await prisma.favorites.deleteMany({ where: { slug: slug, userId: userId } });
```

Comment: To contribute to the answer, the output is `{count: 1}` if it deleted 1 item. And in case the `deleteMany` method name was potentially ambiguous for anyone like it was for me, it deletes only the item that matches BOTH criteria (AND operator). It DOES NOT delete many items matching any of the criteria (OR operator).